# Windows XP Home Serial Key Expired; Product is no longer sold

Tags: windows-activation, windows-xp

I installed Winows XP Home (SP3) Norwegian in a VirtualBox, entered a **valid key**. Activation window says it can't connect to the activation server, okay.. (Message ID 32777)

So I try Windows Update, so I install the genuine thing and next I am prompted by "Needs activation" with a link, (Customer support ID: 0x8DDD1001) I click the link and some IE plugin starts up, when it's done I get a message that roughly translates into:

> The windows edition you are using are no longer being sold.

And then with options to purchase Windows 7.

So MessageID 32777: [Error Message: Unable to Establish a Connection with the Activation Server. Please Check Your Network...](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306153)

I can connect and brows the Internet.

The time on the Windows XP is identical to the current time.

I did a google on my serial key and it didn't show up.

Comment: I really hope this is only a temporary problem.  People who need to re-install after replacing a failed hard drive depend on the online Activation mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have the solution, or actually it worked out by itself..

1. Leave the OS online for about 40-50 minutes for it to figure out it has updates to install.
2. Start -> Shutdown, then it should say If you want updates to be installed before you shut down, Yes please. (I specifically used Shutdown) **If it does not, leave it on longer and check back later**
3. Start the OS and click Start -> Programs -> Activate Windows: Internet -> Not register -> Success.

So solution is to update your Windows XP, by letting it sit online for a while. In my case I couldnt use Windows Update because it wasn't activated.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you call a local [Microsoft Product Activation Center](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950929), and activate your copy over the phone.

Comment: This looks like the right answer (+1).